# Set up formula to accumulate hours from selected benefit

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to set up my google sheet to automatically adjust hours in the top section in the column "Used" when I input data into the details section. for example:
In details section, when I add my benefit from a drop down list and input the hours used, I would like it to be linked to the top section part where it understands which benefit was used and automatically accumulate the hours used in the "Used" column. I would like it to do this everytime an entry is added to which ever benefit is applied.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sumif()` like this in cell `D4`:

`=sumif(B$12:B, B4, C$12:C)`

Comment: Thankyou It worked just the way I wanted it to!